# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not disappears when click outside in iPad

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried so many solutions to resolve this issue. But, i couldn't. The dropdowns are not hiding on outside click. Its only hiding when ii click the other dropdown on the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar dashboard-nav">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav dashboard-menu" id="dashboard-menu-lst">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/buying/home.html" title="">Buying <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu drpdwn-submenu">
                <li class="dashboard-drpdwn-pointer"></li>
                <li>
                    <a data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/buying/submit-RFQ.html" title="">Submit RFQ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/buying/manage-RFQ.html" title="">Manage RFQ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/buying/inquiries-sent-by-me.html" title="">Inquiries Sent by Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown topbar-drpdwn">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/selling/home.html" title="">Selling <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu drpdwn-submenu">
                <li class="dashboard-drpdwn-pointer"></li>
                <li>
                    <a data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/selling/inquiries-received-by-me.html" title="">Inquiries Received by Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/selling/quotations-sent-by-me.html" title="">Quotations Sent by Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-original-title="" href="/dashboard/selling/quotation-invites-received-by-me.html" title="">Invites Received by Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

Replace the 2 lines:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Buying <span class="caret"></span></a>

<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Selling <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

If this is no solution, please post your custom css.